# How to update multiple rows on kendo grid with outside button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a kendo grid with columns as:

[image]

i write a function for Close button, when user select rows by check and click Close button, this will auto update IsClosed Column to "True"

and this is my code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnClose').click(function () {
        var grid = $('#grOrders').data("kendoGrid");
        $.each($('#grOrders :checkbox:checked').closest('tr'), function () {                
            var data = grid.dataItem($(this));
            data.set("IsClosed", true);
        });
    });

});
```

when i test, it only update a first row checked, don't know why? please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that as soon as you invoke a `set("IsClosed", true)` KendoUI redraws the grid so next `grid.dataItem` will not return what you expect.

Instead, try doing a first `each` for getting the list of items that need to be modified and then a second `each` for actually modifying them. Something like:

```
$('#btnClose').click(function () {
    var grid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
    var rows = $('#grid :checkbox:checked');
    var items = [];
    $.each(rows, function () {
        var item = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
        items.push(item);
    });
    $.each(items, function(idx, elem) {
        elem.set("IsClosed", true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it work perfect.Can you show me more?. How can i send this list of items to controller for update database?