# How to show the popupeditor to change values for several records in Kendo?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I have a kendo grid with a standard popup editor.

I want to select many records in my grid and show editor popup
with a empty fields, modify values in the form and these modifications are applied in my grid with button update.

Is is possible?
Do you have a sample?

Comment: Can you share what you have already? Kendo grid has a multiple record editor but not with a popup. The functionality is batch editing and you can get more information here:  https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing

Comment: I don't want this ... I want select n rows in a grid and show popupeditor, change ProductName value, click update and the n records in a grid change too ...

Comment: I think use selectable in columns property and use event edit on the grid ...

Comment: You could, in theory, have a checkbox for each row and then a button that will popup a modal to gather the values followed by code to update all the selected records. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727676/how-to-update-multiple-rows-on-kendo-grid-with-outside-button).

Comment: yes it's a solution but I don't want recode the dafault template .... thanks